# Merging a pandas dataframe with the output of an asyncio call

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-asyncio

So, I have a pandas DataFrame containing sales of several products. It contains a MultiIndex (date, id), as well as qty. I then pass the sales of each product to a forecasting algorithm that outputs a pandas Series with the forecast, which is finally merged into the initial DataFrame. It works more or less like this:

```python
forecasts = sales_df.groupby(level=1).apply(get_forecast)
```

where get_forecast returns a pandas Series containing the forecast, fitted values, error metrics, etc. This was working perfectly fine, but now the forecasting is done through a micro service, so the calls need to be done async in order not to block due to I/O ops.

I'm using asyncio to make the calls and collecting them through asyncio.gather as follows:

```python
sales_grp = sales_df.groupby(level=1)
result = await asyncio.gather(*[pd.Series(get_forecast(group)) for _, group in sales_grp])
```

result is an array of pandas Series, so that is working fine, all async calls are collected through asyncio. The problem is merging them again with the initial dataframe. With the apply function that happens automatically, but not with the way things are done now, since groupby returns a DataFrameGroupBy.

So, in short, how can I merge the result with the grouped dataframe, similar to the sync apply call? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended up doing the following:

1. Build a separate data frame containing only the IDs, which will be concatenated later

```python
sales_grp = sales_df.groupby(level=1)
id_df = pd.DataFrame(sales_grp.groups.keys(), columns=["id"])
```

2. Then, iterate over the grouped lines and call the remote function:

```python
forecasts = await asyncio.gather(*[get_forecast(get_weekly_ts(group)) for _, group in sales_grp])
```

3. Finally, build a data frame with the results (i.e. array of pd.Series) and concatenate back with the ids data frame:

```python
forecasts_df = pd.DataFrame(forecasts)
forecasts_df = pd.concat([sku_df, forecasts_df], axis=1)
```

Extra tip: when doing the remote calls, make sure you do in batches not to overload the micro service and cause a denial of service. Gather 10-50 requests in a list and then await for those results before proceeding further.

Hope this helps someone!